# Normalization constant for uniform distribution over categorical distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose we have a uniform distribution over all categorical distributions **p** for *m* categories, where the pdf has the form

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&c, && 0 \le p_i \le 1, i = 1, ..., m, \textstyle \sum_{1}^{m}p_i = 1 \\
&0, && \textrm{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

How do you show that

$$
c = (m - 1)!
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick update, I have since found the answer to my own question.

Since we are concerned with finding the density of a uniform distribution, *1/c* is the normalization constant for the summation across the set of all categorical distributions of m such that

$$
\textstyle \sum_{1}^{m}p_i = 1
$$

But this set of *m* probabilities is simply an (m-1)-dimensional unit simplex. Therefore the normalization constant *1/c* is just the volume of the (m-1)-dimensional unit simplex, which is equal to

$$
\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\text{det}(v_i - v_0, v_2 - v_0, ..., v_{m-1}-v_0)) = \frac{1}{(m-1)!}
$$

by placing the first vertex at the origin.

Therefore 
$$
c = (m-1)!
$$